# Why the fetching data Get request isn't returning several parameters, instead it returns a single one Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, fetch-api

I'm expecting to get data and visualize a list with a fetch GET request, by passing two parameters. So I'm getting an error 400 when I pass two parameters, and I'm getting data ok when I'm passing a single one.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-hrqfyc?file=src%2Fstore%2Findex.js,src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FArrivalDate.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FArrivalPoint.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDepartureDate.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FDeparturePoint.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlight.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FFlightList.vue,src%2Fmain.js

This doesn't work

```
async getFlights(context, { selectedPoint, departurePoint }) {
    
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=${selectedPoint}&destination=${departurePoint}&show_to_affiliates&token=${context.state.token}`,
  );
  if (res.ok) {
    let result = await res.json();
    context.commit('setFlights', result.data);
  }
  return res.ok;
},
```

This works

```
async getFlights(context, selectedPoint }) {
    
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=${selectedPoint}&destination=LED&show_to_affiliates&token=${context.state.token}`,
  );
  if (res.ok) {
    let result = await res.json();
    context.commit('setFlights', result.data);
  }
  return res.ok;
},
```

This works

```
async getFlights(context, departurePoint }) {
    
  const res = await fetch(
    `http://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=LED&destination=${departurePoint}&show_to_affiliates&token=${context.state.token}`,
  );
  if (res.ok) {
    let result = await res.json();
    context.commit('setFlights', result.data);
  }
  return res.ok;
},
```

Comment: How are you calling the first `getFlights()`?

Comment: I'm calling it from both child componenents as this.$store.dispatch("getFlights", this.selectedPoint)

Comment: There is your problem - the second argument should be an object, not a single value. Related, you're only sending a single value, not two.

Comment: Did you mean this.$store.dispatch("getFlights", { this.selectedPoint })  ?

Comment: basically it is an input object `getFlights(context, obj) ` -> `getFlights(context,{objKey0,objKey1 }) `

Comment: Yes and no. Yes - you should be sending an object, no - that's not a valid syntax to produce an object. Also you need to send ***both*** values. Because the function expects ***both*** values.

Comment: But the point is that I'm sending data from two different components to a single action. Probably that is the problem

Comment: No, the problem is that you have a function that expects two values and you only give it one value. When it tries to fill in the URL, one or both would be `undefined` which is an invalid for whatever API you're calling. Therefore, if you want the function to use both values, either send both or default them or do anything that will ensure that calling with less than the two expected still works.

Comment: So I can't send the data from to different components, as I see. Son I only can create a single component ? But is it the best approach ?

Comment: Is maybe a way to create a parent component to accumulate the child’s both properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vuex and create additional states for selected stuff, for example:

```
state: {
  selectedArival: null,
  selectedDeparture: null,
  ...
},
```

then mutations for them:

```
setSelectedArival(state, data) {
  state.selectedArival = data;
},
setSelectedDeparture(state, data) {
  state.selectedDeparture = data;
},
```

commit them on selection:

```
choosePoint(point) {
  ...
  this.$store.commit('setSelectedDeparture', this.selectedPoint);
  // this.$store.commit('setSelectedArival', this.selectedPoint); from other component
  ...
  // before dispatching getFlights
}
```

and change action to:

```
async getFlights(context) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=rub&origin=${context.state.selectedDeparture}&destination=${context.state.selectedArival}&show_to_affiliates=true&token=${context.state.token}`
  );
  ...
}
```